# Hamburger meat falling apart

Tags: beef, hamburgers, ground-beef

I ran the meat through mincer once, formed burger approx. 3cm high, seasoned it, oiled from one side and put it in very heated pot and I put the lid on it. When I was turning it the other side down, it started to fall apart.

What do I need to change in my process to keep the hamburger whole? I guess the flaw can be that the meat is not enough oily, it didn't taste very oily. But the meat that I have isn't oily, will adding some external oil fix it?

Comment: beside the duplicate, also see the other question from the "related" list, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/826/how-to-stop-meatballs-falling-apart-when-frying